# How to create a different list of buttons with sweetalert based on the returned result of an asynchronous function?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I'm very very new at working so deep with javascript so i'm starting to have some troubles.
I have a list of 'Bike Stations' in my database and i have created an algorithm which gets me the neighbours of each station based on the longitute and latitude coordinates of each station. What i'm trying to do, is to create a SweetAlert with buttons representing those stations, which on click to call another function ( a function to zoom on the selected location ).

`resolved`. The `GetNeighbours` algorithm is an asynchronous function and for some reason i'm not able to get the expected result in the function where i'm trying to create the SweetAlert. `resolved`

**Any idea on what am i doing wrong when i try to create the sweet alert dynamically?**

Here is my `GetNeighbours` function:

```
async function GetAllNeighboors(myLocationLat, myLocationLong,cb) {
     $.get("/Home/GetAllLocation",
        function (data, status) {
            Neightbours = new Array();
            var j = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (distanceBetweenTwoStations(myLocationLat, myLocationLong, data[i].latitudine, data[i].longitudine,"K") <= 1 && data[i].latitudine != myLocationLat && data[i].longitudine != myLocationLong) {
                    Neightbours[j] = data[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            cb(Neightbours);        
        });     
}
```

And here is the pice of code, where i'm trying to create the SweetAlert:

```
                   ]).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                             GetAllNeighboors(data.latitudine, data.longitudine, function (Neighboors) {
                        Vecini = new Array();
                        Vecini = Neighboors;
                    });
                                    for (var i = 0; i < Vecini.length; v++) {
                                        Swal.fire({
                                            html:'<button id='+Vecini[i].id+'class=btn btn-success>'+Vecini[i].name,
                                            title: 'Here is your list',
                                            backdrop: `rgba(0,0,123,0.4)`,                                            
                                        });
                                        onBeforeOpen: () => {
                                            const button = v[i].id;
                                            button.addEventListener('click',
                                                () => {
                                                    GoToLocation(Vecini[i].id);
                                                });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Update: with the help of another fellow, i managed to get the result from the `GetAllNeighbours` function. I Updated the code and the question.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The function GetAllNeighboors is supposed to return an array. So in success callback the value of 'v' will be an array. But why you are checking v.value there ?

Comment: it's just a mock up, let's say. i tried any method to see if i was getting what i wanted in `v`.

Comment: Are you getting v as an array

Comment: Actually i'm not getting anything in `v`....